# How to root Genymotion Android Emulator?

Tags: android, genymotion

I have downloaded Genymotion Android Emulator for personal use. I searched over internet to root this device, forums says that via adb shell its already rooted -"agreed".

```
Sumits-MacBook-Pro:sdk eSumit$ adb -s 192.168.57.102:5555 shell
root@vbox86p:/ # 
root@vbox86p:/ # whoami
root
```

Found Genymotion configure apk, it will help to root access, if checkbox  get clicked - "always allow su access", I did that as well, and then it get stuck like here. (see below)

If I restart by myself, it shows that no root access ?

May I know what I am missing here ?

Here are the pictures sequence :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also followed various tutorials e.g. [Youtube - how to root genymotion emulator Android 7.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YC9Bz5xVHCU)  but no solution yet

Comment: Genymotion images are all rooted in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is some problem with the `su` binary. You can re-install it by downloading SuperSU zip archive and dropping it onto the device window. Restart will be needed.

Please note that the [current version](http://www.supersu.com/download#zip) (2.79) does not seem to work due to missing `/etc/fstab` file on Genymotion systems. It works fine with [2.46](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/supersu/).

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YC9Bz5xVHCU

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have already installed Genymotion ARM Translation.If already,
Drag UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip to Genymotion Emulator(not sure other versions of SuperSU zips), and drop on it.It will confirm to flash zip file to emulator, click OK .After waiting for a while, you will get successfully message.Then, restart your emulator and check it with any Root Check App.Here is [Tools](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4awwBANDgZedEtpYkhmUHoxRkk?resourcekey=0-shUGVHpOdLIVPFKjlT7otw&usp=sharing) file if you haven't it.I tested it on Google Nexus 5,Android 6.0 Emulator.I hope this will help for you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it uses Iso file mounting system like Bluestacks that's why I guess it can't be rooted and also if it says its rooted then you can use UltraISO to modify root files only if it uses ISO file system.

Comment: Since I am very new on these keywords e.g. what this means : "UltraISO"

Comment: @SumitArora UltraISO is a application which have the ability to mount and modify a ISO file with udf header, you can use it to Modify files of the emulator if it only uses Iso file systems.