# How to view the tables of Room Database in sqlite DB browser?

Tags: android, android-room

I am using RoomDB in my sample app.i am able to perform CRUD operation on DB. but i am not able to view db file.i want to view table structure in sqlite DB browser.

this is my **APPDatabase** class

```
 @Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;  
    public abstract UserDao userDao();        
    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "user-database")                                
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }    
    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

help me to get DB file.

Comment: See this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429372/view-contents-of-database-created-with-room-persistence-library

Comment: you cant find it in its place or you dont know the place?

Comment: see `Context#getDatabasePath` method

Comment: @pskink but how and where to use this ? in which file

Comment: in any `Activity` for example

Comment: @pskink yes it is giving the path like this /data/data/com.example.manvish.roomdb/databases/user.db but there is no folder called data in memory..is it possible to change the path

Comment: @pskink permission denied even after using sudo

Comment: @pskink still permission denied

Comment: so does `adb shell` work or not? what do you see when you run `adb shell` on your terminal window?

Comment: @pskink adb shell works.. i am able to access other files but not data folder

Comment: @pskink geting error /system/bin/sh: cd: bad substitution

Comment: @pskink yes cd data will change the directory but after that for evry operation i will get error as permission denies ..even ls also not able to list the files inside that folder..

Comment: @pskink ls -ld /data giving output like drwxrwx--x system   system            2018-02-21 10:14 data

Comment: I have a problem like this , please check  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628647/android-room-database-file-is-invalid-file-format-in-db-browser](this)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have done it. In Android Studio 3.1,

1. Access to View>Tool Windows>Device File Explorer.
2. Navigate to folder /data/data/`<your package>`/databases
3. Save your database file which ended with .db

If you can't see your database file, consider to copy the file with following code

```
fun exportDB(context: Context){
        try {
            val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                val backupDBPath = "database.db"
                val currentDB = context.getDatabasePath("database.db")
                val backupDB = File(sd, backupDBPath)

                val src = FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel()
                val dst = FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel()
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
                src.close()
                dst.close()
                Log.i("database","export database done. Original path: $currentDB")
            }else{
                Log.i("database","cannot write database")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("database","export database failed. "+e.message)
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: [the db file is empty, and u need .db-shm and .db-wal to open .db file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372487/android-room-database-file-is-empty)